# RecyclerView "Cannot resolve symbol" error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to setup a RecyclerView in my Android Project but i cannot refer to my list because using the code "recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.list)" give me the error Cannot resolve symbol "list". If I try to type "R.id." i cannot find R.id.list but I'm sure that I give it the id "list".

I just added dependencies and the import statement in my code. I tried to resync and clean project but with no result.

here my dependencies (build.gradle (app)):

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

here my import:

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

here the wrong code:

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

          recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    }
```

here the declaration of the RecyclerView in the xml file:

```
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to clean & re building code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

Also, shift this code to onCreateView()

```
recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Where view should be the view you get after inflating.

Comment: Solved! I just tried to File>Invalidate Cache/Restart and it was enough to fix it!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Close the project and try to remove .gradle and .idea with rm -r /pathToYourProject/.gradle and than open your project and sync it

Answer (score 0):

Try in your activity:

```
 import your.project.name.R;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you forget somthing

just set this line before `recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.list);`

```
setContentview(R.layout.THE_LAYOUT_THAT_CONTAIN_YOUR_RECYCLERVIEW);
```